# File upload with title

Tags: files

I want functionality where editor will be able to upload files and name that files whatever he wants, I just want additional field next to file upload field, is there any module which can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: check this https://drupal.org/project/ocupload

Comment: Thank you for comment, I solved my problem using insert module but it seems ocupload is another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is already provided by Drupal core. Just edit the settings for your image field in content type and enable 'Enable Title field' to have Title field for your image field.

For example,
Go to 'Structure » Content types » Article' and 'Edit' the settings for 'Image' field. (admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/field_image)

There you will see two checkbox fields 'Enable Alt field' and 'Enable Title field' which can be enabled to provide image related info for each image upload.

Comment: the Title and Alt mentioned here create content for the `alt=` and `title=` attributes within the resulting `<img>` tag; they don't cause the uploaded file to be renamed `value of title/alt`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using [insert](http://drupal.org/project/insert) module, it did exactly what I wanted.

When I upload any file for example .pdf, there is a description field for every file.

[insert](http://drupal.org/project/insert) module also integrates with ckeditor, every uploaded file has "Send to textarea" button and you can easily embed links to attachments wherever you want in your editor and title will be the text you entered in file description.

It is not file name, its just title for link but its exactly what I wanted.

UPDATE
@amitgoyal's answer is better, so I checked his answer as correct.